# Introductory topics to teach after *Linear Algebra Done Right*

Tags: linear-algebra

I am teaching Sheldon Axler's book *Linear Algebra Done Right* and I want to add some introductory topics to related and advanced courses after this book to my students, or some topics in linear algebra that are not mentioned in this book.

Which topics and references are recommended?

Comment: It seems a book devoted on linear algebra over real or complex fields. I personally think math students should know a little bit of linear algebra over arbitrary field.

Comment: This is difficult for us to answer, as the answers depend on the strengths/interests of the students and, likewise, on your strengths/interests and background. Are you trying to go further in pure mathematics or show them some applications (e.g., computer graphics)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Pure mathematics. I hope the topics are introductory and easy to be understood.

Comment: Cool. Well, if you look at section 2 of chapter 7 of my book with Adams, *Linear Algebra, a Geometric Approach*, you’ll see some projective geometry and applications of eigenvalues/eigenvectors to geometry and projective geometry. Similarly, you can use linear algebra to classify isometries of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Polytopes! I would recommend taking selections from the beginning of Lectures on Polytopes; if you have time, duality is always an exciting topic, or if you want, Gale diagrams use the null space of a matrix to encode face-lattice structure in a picture 2 dimensions lower than the relevant polytope.

Comment: Polynomials. Start by unlearning the wrong definition from Axler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fun ideas that you might want to explore with your students superficially, without getting bogged down in details:

- realising the complex numbers and quaternions through real matrices
- solving linear recurrences by means of eigenvalues
- on a related note, the look-and-say sequence http://www.nathanieljohnston.com/2010/10/a-derivation-of-conways-degree-71-look-and-say-polynomial/
- numerical linear algebra, i.e. algorithms [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/classes/nla_2015/numerical_linear_algebra.pdf](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/classes/nla_2015/numerical_linear_algebra.pdf)
- linear algebra in combinatorics [https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/CLASS/HANDOUTS-COMB/BaFrNew.pdf](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/CLASS/HANDOUTS-COMB/BaFrNew.pdf)
- Jacobians in multivariable calculus
- the resultant of pairs of polynomials

$\\$

In undergraduate maths programs, linear algebra leads naturally to modules over rings, representation theory and functional analysis.

Comment: I did my master's talk on the look and say sequence :).   Unpacking the original paper was a fun exercise.   The hardest thing was to realize that the math requires you to work in an "infinite" base,  or rather a base high enough for the collapsing that occurs after day 3 to all be a single digit

Answer (score 0):

I can give a very interesting sequence once one does Linear algebra. There turns out to be complex function whose composition turns out to have the exact same structure as matrix multiplication known as mobius functions. These function have deep geometric insight relating to projective geometry and allows nice re-interpretations of concepts such as eigen values, eigen vectors etc.

A very good elementary introduction to do this topic comes in Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis Chapter-3.